# Как найти страницу где есть запись при OFFSET и LIMIT (постраничная навигация)?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица данных где выводятся записи по 10 строк на страницу (постраничная навигация).
Нужно, зная id конкретной записи, узнать на какой странице находится эта запись. и запросить её. То есть какой OFFSET выставить чтобы эта запись точно попала в запрос.

```
// При таком запросе получаю записи со смещением. Это страница 3
SELECT id,name FROM table1 ORDER BY DESC OFFSET 20 LIMIT 10
```

Вот как узнать номер страницы или смещения OFFSET для id=17 где в запрос попадёт эта запись с id 17?
Запрос может быть с разными условиями WHERE.

Comment: А order by ЧТО у вас в запросе ? Если ID, то просто посчитать count() всех записей, что больше 17. Если НЕ ID, то боюсь единственный способ перенумеровать записи row_number в той же сортировке и просто посмотреть порядковый номер строки с id=17. И все это разумеется со всеми условиями where

Comment: Не id. Там сортировка и условия могут быть разные.

Comment: А как сделать запрос с этим  row_number? Есть похожие примеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу два способа. Пусть `X` - поле, по которому идет сортировка, тогда количество записей с X большими, чем в искомой записи, деленное на размер страницы даст нам номер этой страницы:

```
  SELECT count(1) / 10
    FROM table1
   WHERE X > (select X from Table1 where id=17)
```

Или нумеруем все записи в нужном порядке сортировки и получаем номер требуемой записи, который так же делим на размер страницы

```
select rn / 10
  FROM (
    SELECT id, row_number() over(OREDER BY X DESC) RN
      FROM Table1 ....
  ) X
 where id=17
```

Первый способ представляется мне более быстрым, при наличии индекса по полю `X`.

Comment: Спасибо! Первый способ то что нужно. Работает с любыми условиями и сортровками вроде.